# Functions in $H_0^s(U)$ disappear on their boundaries?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

I have an issue in a proof I face. I have a function $f$ in $H^s_0(U)$, where $U$ is bounded with $C^1$-boundary. Then I would like to say that $f=0$ on $\partial U$ however this is not necessarily the case, no?

I think, I need make sure $f$ is also continuous and that a trace operator exists, but this seems only to be ensured if the domain’s boundary is in addition Lipschitz.

Or does this hold anyway?

Comment: To even make sense of the phrase "$f = 0$ on $\partial U$, you need to have the trace $f|_{\partial U}$ defined. The trace is well defined as an element of $H^{s - 1/2}(\partial U)$ for $s > 1/2$. I believe the proof via coordinate transformation reduction works for $C^1$ boundary, and probably can be adapted to Lipschitz boundary. See Taylor's PDE book and Evans PDE book and a Sobolev space reference for details.